# UWP Toolkit Onedrive null reference exception

Tags: uwp, onedrive, toolkit, windows-community-toolkit

Odd thing happened. My app and also UWP community Toolkit sample app stopped working when trying to access Onedrive service. 
If I choose OnlineId (microsoft account), OneDriveService.Instance gives null reference exception.
If I choose to you client id, popup window open for login but then reports error: "Technical problems with your microsoft account".

What is wrong? My windows 10 machine (Thinkpad T440s) correctly syncs my OneDrive. OneDrive App of Microsoft works ok. I can access all features of my onedrive with Microsoft office and web browsers.

I ran microsoft account troubleshooter, but it did not help at all!! It does report error "can not connect sync server", but I can not say how that can be related.

My network connection is working (I can write this post)...

I have tried 3 different microsoft accounts. My app is registered to MS Graph and I have valid clientid for it. But this should not be the problem since UWP communinity toolkit sample app also fails - even when using onlineid.

Any hint?? Any suggestions??

Comment: Can you add the stack trace that shows where the `NullReferenceException` is coming from?

Comment: var folder = await instance.RootFolderAsync();

Comment: App is associated with the store. It should not be the problem. And as I wrote, UWP Toolkit sample app (installed from the Store) fails too